# Align LazyVGrid columns to the top

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a TabView with a LazyVGrid. Attempting to align my items to the top of the view. When I scroll to the next page, would like the items to also align to the top. As of now the items are appearing directly in the middle of the View.

[image]

```
             TabView {
                   ForEach(Array(rm.recipes.chunked(into: 4)), id: \.self) { recipesChunk in
                       LazyVGrid(columns: columns) {
                          ForEach(recipesChunk, id: \.id) { recipe in
                             Text("Test")
                          }
                       }
                   }
               }
           .tabViewStyle(.page)
           .gesture(
               DragGesture()
                  .onEnded { value in
                      if value.translation.width < 0 {
                          self.currentPage = min(self.currentPage + 1, rm.recipes.count / 4)
                  } else if value.translation.width > 0 {
                      self.currentPage = max(self.currentPage - 1, 0)
                  }
              }
            )
```

Comment: Put an ```HStack(alignment: .top)``` around your TabView and add an ```Spacer()``` underneath

Comment: Tried this unfortunately before. didn't work :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set a specific height and alignment for your LazyVGrid.

Like this:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var data: Array<Array<String>> {
        let data0 = ["1", "2"]
        let data1 = ["3"]
        return [data0, data1]
    }

    let columns = Array(repeating: GridItem(.flexible(), spacing: 6), count: 1)

    var body: some View {
        TabView() {
            ForEach(data, id: \.self) { data in
                LazyVGrid(columns: columns, spacing: 50) {
                    ForEach(data, id: \.self) { data in
                        Text(data)
                    }
                }.frame(height: 50, alignment: .top) // <- HERE
            }
        }.tabViewStyle(.page)
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response, but looks like you're missing TabView

Comment: Arh, sorry I did not realize how much that affected it. I have adjusted my answer. You need to set a specific height for your LazyVGrid and then set the alignment to top. .frame(height: 300, alignment: .top) - But if I were you I would try to implement this without using a TabView - they can be a real horror to work with, and this is a great example of rather strange behavior.

Comment: I actually made a minor adjustment correcting to .frame(maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .top) , but thank you for this!